# How to use gcc for macro expansion only in a non C/C++ context?

Tags: gcc, macros, expansion

How can I use gcc to expand macros in files containing (for example) python/php/perl code?

Having a file containing:

```
#define foo very important stuff
#define feast Christmas

I should take care of some foo for feast.
```

I have tried to use:

```
$ gcc -x c++ -E - < text.txt > output.txt
```

but it displays this:

```
$ cat output.txt
# 1 "<stdin>"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "<stdin>"



I should take care of some very important stuff for Christmas.
```

How to avoid gcc to add those comments and (if possible) the extra newlines?

Comment: Why using C preprocessor? M4 fits your requirements better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be aware of this warning from [the online docs for the GNU C preprocessor](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/)

> The C preprocessor is intended to be
>   used only with C, C++, and Objective-C
>   source code. In the past, it has been
>   abused as a general text processor. It
>   will choke on input which does not
>   obey C's lexical rules. For example,
>   apostrophes will be interpreted as the
>   beginning of character constants, and
>   cause errors. Also, you cannot rely on
>   it preserving characteristics of the
>   input which are not significant to
>   C-family languages. If a Makefile is
>   preprocessed, all the hard tabs will
>   be removed, and the Makefile will not
>   work.

The '#' lines in the output could be the least of your problems.

You might do better with a different tool, such as m4.

Comment: m4 is indeed a better choice in my case, many thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if there is a specific option for gcc.

You can postprocess with a grep

```
$ gcc -x c++ -E - < text.txt | grep -v '^#' > output.txt
```

Comment: I though about this but lines beginning with # should be kept from the original source.